# Two dynamic lists, adjusting to each other

Tags: android

I have to make two RecyclerViews, that can dynamically adjust its heights to each other. Assume i have a screen = 1/3 of its height is first RV and next 2/3 of its height us second RV. This is normal state for two populated lists. But if first RV doesn't have enough elements to fill 1/3 of screen - second RV becomes higher and if seconds RV doesn't have enough elements to fill 2/3 of screen height - first list become taller.

Is this theoretically possible? If yes, can you give me some clues to start digging?

Comment: wrap_content ?..recyclerview width

Comment: You can add layout_weight to 1 in both of them to make them same height even if they have items or not. And you can have there height to wrap_content then if the first one has more items then it will take more space and the other one will be smaller

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
private int itemHeight = "height of item layout which u are inflating in the recycler view"

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = recyclerView.getLayoutParams();

```
    params.height = itemHeight * numberOfItemInList;

    recyclerView.requestLayout();
```

Comment: itemHeight has to be in pixel.